# Can you turn off automatic download of background map data?

Tags: python, cartopy

I have some code that is supposed to run in a 24/7 operational environment behind firewalls with restrictions on internet access. It use cartopy to produce some plots (satellite swath coverage on a globe). In operations we do not want Cartopy to even try downloading what it thinks it needs. It os then better that it fails saying what (background - shapefile) data it cannot get.

Is it possible to turn off downloading completely?

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(cartopy.config)

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

proj_info = {'central_latitude': 58,
             'central_longitude': 16,
             'satellite_height': 35785831,
             'false_easting': 0,
             'false_northing': 0,
             'globe': None}

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.NearsidePerspective(**proj_info))

ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN, zorder=0)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, zorder=0, edgecolor='black')
ax.set_global()
ax.gridlines()

plt.savefig('./cartopy_test.png')
```

The above code runs fine locally, but fails in our test-environment where we have stricter internet access.

Comment: Why not just remove the lines (the two `ax.add_feature` calls) that are trying to download features? If you're on a system that never has internet access then you'll never be able to add these features anyway? Alternatively if you do need to add these features you could download the shapefiles for them on another system and copy them to the appropriate location on the firewalled operational system.

Comment: @DPeterK that's the point, of course it *will* succeed if the files are already downloaded, which they should be in a production environment. What Adam is asking for is a flag to tell it that anything that's missing *can't* be downloaded, so don't even try.

Comment: Exactly @hobbs I actually didn't know that my code was accessing the internet until I was ready to put it in operations. Naturally that is why we have a test-environemnt which is identical to operations, only difference is that the end products are not reaching customers and monitoring is not trickering alerts to the operators. Without being able to shut down downloading I could imagine that a new version of Cartopy could cause my application to fail, just because it thinks that it needs newer/better background maps that I haven't downloaded already.